# Schedule Notification with specified date

Tags: swift, notifications, ios10, localnotification, unusernotificationcenter

I want to implement scheduled notification(in iOS 10) using `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` or `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` with `repeat` parameter as `true` for 2-3 consecutive days. Later on I can update or delete notification for upcoming days. e.g I scheduled notification on `13 Nov 2017` and I wanted to repeat this till `17 Nov 2017` at `10AM` in morning and on `15 Nov 2017` I wanted to change the schedule time of notification for next 2days i.e (`16 Nov` and `17 Nov`).

So can you please suggest me what are the alternatives or how this can be achieved?

Comment: The best I can suggest is to look out on the Appel documentation here about Local Notifications : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html

Comment: @Arrabidas92 Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use a trigger for that.

```
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
```

To create the dateComponents to match your needs you have to do for example:

```
// Matching specific minute and hour
let unitFlags = Set<Calendar.Component>([.hour, .minute])
dateComponents = NSCalendar.current.dateComponents(unitFlags, from: givenDate)

// Matching specific weekday, hour and minute
let unitFlags = Set<Calendar.Component>([.weekday, .hour, .minute])
dateComponents = NSCalendar.current.dateComponents(unitFlags, from: givenDate)

// Matching specific day, hour and minute
let unitFlags = Set<Calendar.Component>([.day, .hour, .minute])
dateComponents = NSCalendar.current.dateComponents(unitFlags, from: givenDate)
```